# navigation property to soft-deleted entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 2 entites:
Im my DB they look like:

```
Vehicles(Id, VehicleNumber, IsDeleted, WorkerId)   
Workers(Id, Name, Address)
```

And in my edmx:

```
VehicleId: Id, VehicleNumber, IsDeleted, WorkerId, Worker
Workers: Id, Name, Address, VehiclesList
```

As you can see, Vehicles table contains soft deleted rows. Now when I get Worker with id=2, I got all his vehicles, including the one I soft deleted. How can I retrieve only the undeleted vehicles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badly. EF has very limited support for soft deletes. Actually the only possibility is using conditional mapping where you explicitly hardcode (it cannot be changed at runtime) to your mapping condition saying that you don't want to load entities having `IsDeleted = 0`. Check mapping details:

[image]

But it has very bad consequences:

- `IsDeleted` column cannot be mapped - it already defines mapping internally
- Your model can never be used to load soft deleted entities even if you want

The first problem can be solved by mapping stored procedure to delete operation for the `Vehicle` entity and the second problem can be solved by separate model for auditing and retrieving deleted entities.

Also conditional mapping is not supported by code first - it requires EDMX file.

Answer (score 1):

is lazyloading enabled? then try to limit result set with a where:

```
worker.VehiclesList.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted)
```

also you can put a condition to a vehicles table mapping in model desiner isdeleted = false. Soft deleted vehicles will not be retrived at all